# Why do I have to avoid cached results?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, get

I am new in AJAX and I find this one very confusing. Please help me figure it out.
I pursue the curriculum of w3schools and I got this example from here:

> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

I didn't understand what is the difference between cached file and non cached file in these two examples because both examples deliver the same results and why do I have to add a unique Id to the url?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request an url, the browser or other proxys on the way to the server might cache the result, so if you request it more than once, it will be delivered faster. But the content might get out of date.

If you change the url, the caching mechanism between, from browser and other proxys on the way, will not recognize the request as the former request. 
If you keep sending the same number, it might get cached, so it has to be unique.

But you cannot avoid a cached result from the server itself

Comment: Caching mechanism between browser and server speeds up file delivery. knowing that, why I should avoid cache using that unique Id? and the results of both examples above aren't the same, though there are different links in url, why the results are still the same?

Comment: and please explain this "but the content might get out of date", because the content of none of those two urls are out of date

Comment: content that ist stored in cache might be out of date, but you will not know for sure. Since the caching "on the way" is usually just done by url, adding a unique key will always ask for a different url and therfor caching will not apply.
If you dont want to cache, because the content might have a calculation or time-dependend information, you want the actual data.
If the real content on server changes, but you still get the cached content, you will have obsolete information.